# I have a svg file content and I want to remove a string based on matching substring

Tags: java, string

How I can remove *Author: SHARMSR* based on matching condition *Author* from the below string

```
<text fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" font-family="Arial" font-size="10" font-style="normal" font-weight="400" stroke="none" textLength="84.875" x="-42.4375" xml:space="preserve" y="3.5">Author: SHARMSR</text>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a simple regex in `String.replaceAll`

```
String s = "<text fill=\"#000000\"  y=\"3.5\">Author: SHARMSR</text>";
String result = s.replaceAll("Author[^<]+", "");
System.out.println(s);      // <text fill="#000000"  y="3.5">Author: SHARMSR</text>
System.out.println(result); // <text fill="#000000"  y="3.5"></text>
```